# Remote Debugging of Openstack

Tags: python, django, web2py, pylons, openstack

I'm working on openstack, we are connecting client hosts through VPN. How do I debug that openstack running in my local,

I tried some links but not successful.

In which way I go...?

Comment: the clients themselves ( including methods ) have a debug flag that can be used... triggered by a --debug in cli query or env export of DEBUG=TRUE ( or something similar )

Answer (score 2):

There is an article explaining the exact problem you have right now you can check it here:

- [Debug Openstack code Local / Remote with Eclipse and PyDev](http://debugopenstack.blogspot.com.tr/)